Upgrading to smart 3-way switch with existing non-grounded switch
I have been upgrading my dumb switches with some new matter based smart ones. My home was built in 1997, so there are ground bundles in the boxes, but the existing switches do not have a ground connection.
When upgrading single pole switches I obviously connect ground to the new smart switch.
What is the best approach for grounding when upgrading to a smart 3-way or 4-way switch where the old non grounded dumb switches work in conjunction with the main smart switch?

What country are you located in? Please post a picture of one of these old switches (see the Edit link, Mountain icon).

Ground is usually a bare or green/yellow covered wire.  Neutral which most smart switches need to be connected to also, is white or your location neutral colour.  Usually if you have a bundle of grounds, you also should have a bundle of neutrals.

Ground wires are intended to carry current only when there is a failure in the electrical system that would give the current a path through your body.
Given that ground wires are a protection against failures and not part of the operation of switches or other equipment, you should not have any second thoughts about connecting ground anywhere.
If your switch has a screw to connect a ground wire, use it (unless you know for a fact that the ground will be picked up by the connection to the metal box). If it has a factory-attached ground wire, definitely use it.

Some North American switches have a specific screw to attach ground, or the box screw provides the ground if the box is metal and grounded.  In these cases effort should be made to attach ground. Switches. from other locations may be different.

@Triplefault, I don't see how your comment relates to what I wrote. Was it meant as an addendum?

It's a suggestion about something to put in, if I might offer it. What I see of European switches is that they're all encased in plastic, so theoretically no way for electricity to leak and maybe no ground needed. USA switches at least have metal screws on the surface for the switch plates, and these screws attach to the metal body strap of the switch. Electricity from a loose live wire in the box could get on the metal body strap then through the switch plate screws to the person. Grounding USA switches is necessary. Depending on OP's switch type they should consider connecting ground.

This rather depends on where you are, and therefore what kind of switch you have.
Some jurisdictions' switches are completely encased in plastic, with no metal - not even screws - showing on the outside. There is no way for house power to get out of the device if a wire comes loose and touches something it should not be touching.
USA switches (likely others as well) have metal screws holding the switchplate covers on. These screws attach to the metal mounting strap of the switch body. If a loose wire touches that strap, house power can get to the person touching the switchplate screw and give them a dangerous shock.
Effort should be made to ground any device being wired in that has metal on its outside.
Additionally, if the manufacturer put a screw or wire for ground on the device, then there is a foreseen possibility that there is a risk of electric leakage through the device. They don't put in extra parts that drive up manufacturing costs that aren't needed.
TL;DR: If there is a ground wire or ground screw on the device, ground it. There is a reason the ground point is there.

If you're planning to open up and ground the "dumb" switches I recommend replacing them.  For the amount of effort needed to rearrange the wires, you may as well spend a dollar or two for a brand new switch at the same time.
Also consider in cold or dry climates with carpeting, adding the ground may change your experience with the switches.  Carpeting can cause static buildup that will discharge if your fingers are near a grounded surface such as a faceplate screw.  One good way to prevent that is to get the "screwless" type faceplate that has no exposed metal parts.

If by chance a live wire touches metal on the back of the switch, house power can get to the switchplate screws too, causing an electrocution risk.
